# Class selector won't fire click event in jquery for dynamically inserted elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar with a list of generated divs each of which have a p tag inside of them that contain the name of a font. I'm trying to get the text in the p tag. For some reason my code isn't working for the dynamically added elements, but it works on other elements I've tried it with.

HTML (Template)

```
var content = '<div class="trending-font d-flex w-100 justify-content-between list-group-item"><p>' + item.family + '</p><small>' + item.lastModified + '</small></div>';
```

JS

```
$('.trending-font').click(function () {
    var $sideBarFont = $(this).find('p').text();
    console.log($sideBarFont);
});
```

When I run it there are no errors and nothing on the page is broken it just doesn't return the text inside of the clicked div.

[image: The sidebar to help visulize]

Comment: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: The information that you have supplies shows the content that you are looking for is within a variable and not part of the web page itself. That is why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate the event since the `div`s are appended on the fly to the DOM.

```
$(document).on('click', '.trending-font', function () {
    var $sideBarFont = $(this).find('p').text();
    console.log($sideBarFont);
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.trending-font', function () {
    var $sideBarFont = $(this).find('p').text();
    console.log($sideBarFont);
});

var content = '<div class="trending-font d-flex w-100 justify-content-between list-group-item" ><p> family 1 </p><small> Jan 3, 2018</small></div>';

$('#c').append( Array(5).join(content) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c"></div>
```

Comment: It worked! I also didn't know about needing to do things differently when content is generated dynamically like that. I'll give you a check when I can!